# Execute APK background at scheduled time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have developed an app of my own that automatically sends a daily e-mail to several people.

I would like to know how can I run this app every day at the same time automatically, because I am a little forgetful

I've seen an Android class that is AlarmManager, but I really don't know how I can use this class to run automatically my app, so if anyone knows how to do this wiht a helpful example or code, I will appreciate it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: You can use service which when started will always run so that it may send based on some logics

Comment: OK, i will take a look at the alarm page, and if I find a solution I will post the code here if anyone is interested